# Is the speed of light related to the mass of the universe?

Tags: gravity, mass, speed-of-light, terminology

If the mass of the universe were cut in half, would it affect the speed of light?

Would it be twice as fast?

Would it stay the same?

Do we have instruments that are sensitive enough to measure the speed of light at different positions relative to high-mass objects to empirically answer this question?

The speed of light is (something of) a universal constant, but is it really dependent on the universe or on something intrinsic to photons?

**EDIT:**

Related question:

Since gravity is a relationship between one atom and every other atom in the entire universe, and it takes all the energy in the universe to travel at the speed of light, is there something about the energy/gravity/mass of the universe that "slows" light from going a faster speed?

Comment: It's not possible to define whether c changes from one place to another. It's only possible to define whether a unitless parameter such as the fine structure constant changes. See Duff, 2002, "Comment on time-variation of fundamental constants," http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0208093

Comment: @BenCrowell: is that because (at c speeds) time passes in a noticeably different way that is relative with respect to an observer?

Comment: No, it's for the reasons described in the paper that I linked to.

Comment: Where ever you heard or read *"it takes all the energy in the universe to travel at the speed of light"*, you should not take it as a definition, it's a poetic way of saying you would need arbitrarily large amounts of energy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The speed of light is entirely a local concept - it does not care if there are 10 atoms or 10 billion galaxies somewhere in the Universe.

Obviously we can't go to distant galaxies to directly measure the speed of light, so in the absolutely strictest sense this is not *directly* empirically tested. However, the constancy of the speed of light is one of the most fundamental tenets of physics. In some sense, just about every observation we make in astronomy tests it, for if there were any variation it would manifest in all sorts of crazy ways in every single system we look at.

The confusion seems to stem from the term "universal." The word "universal" means "fundamental" or "unchanging in space and time" or "lies at the heart of our theoretical framework, permeating everything we do." It does not mean "tied to the Universe" or "depends on global properties of the Universe." Along the same lines, a scented candle could be said to have an "earthy" scent, but this has nothing to do with it being located on Earth the planet.

Comment: My interest was not so much the word "universal" as much as the fact that it takes all the energy in the universe to go the speed of light.

Comment: @micahhoover Ahh, I see. Well, it takes *more* than all the energy in the universe to accelerate any massive particle to $c$, no matter what universe you are in - it just can't be done. When people say it takes all the energy in the universe, what they mean is that no finite amount of energy will suffice, and the entire universe is the "closest thing to infinity" they care to imagine for the comparison. Things that *do* move at $c$, like photons, are simply always doing that - nothing ever accelerated them, and nothing will decelerate them.

Comment: I think it's even misleading to say "it takes [amount of energy] to accelerate a massive object to the speed of light," regardless of what the amount of energy is (yes, even if it's "infinite energy"). It's just impossible to make a massive object move at $c$. No matter how much energy you have, it cannot be done.

Comment: @David Zaslavsky... if you were to accelerate an object to the speed of C - planck's constant or C - 1/100planck's constant botch which have enormous but finite energy requirements... could quantum mechanics (ie the combination of uncertainty and fuzziness/quantum jumping) allow you to accelerate to C or beyond it?

Comment: Ignore the comment I am going to post as a separate question

Comment: @DavidZ "*It's just impossible to make a massive object move at $c$*" - Not even while crossing the event horizon of a black hole?

Comment: @frogeyedpeas Local speeds beyond $c$ don't exist in the spacetime geometry. As an illustration, can you move to the North of the North Pole? No. Not because you don't have enough ability, but simply because there is no such a place, nowhere to go. It does not exist in the geometry of the sphere. Quantum effects won't matter, because the kinetic energy of a particle in its own rest frame is always zero no matter how fast you move relative to it. If quantum effects did matter, the particle would "see" you jumping to the speed of light at the same time as you see it doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

More of a speculation - doesn't red shift & time dilation cause a photon to see all the universe contracted to a point directly ahead of it? So, couldn't the speed of light be determined by the gravitational attraction on a massless particle of the whole universe? And, since the speed of light is not infinite, doesn't this imply that the universe (at least the one we can see) is not infinite, also? That light has a speed then would also mean there's a time (13.8 billion years ago, or more if latest Webb observations are confirmed) beyond which the universe becomes undefined. In fact, maybe the early inflation of the universe is an artifact - a time when the universe appears to us smaller - so with a larger Plank distance, so a less precise subdividing of time & space. As time & space got more precisely defined, they appeared bigger. Just some sci-fi speculation for entertainment purposes only - maybe.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/428782)